# Plus and Minus button update

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with a table that has a column with a Plus and Minus button either side of an text input field. The column is named QUANTITY and the plus buttons can increment to 10; if the button is clicked after the value of 10 the click is set to null. That is fine and working; regarding the minus button; if the value drops below 1, the whole row is removed.
This is also working; the problem is when I click either button in row number x, all the other rows are affected either increasing or decreasing in value. I need the code to only update the  row that is active. Here is the HTML and JavaScript.

```
<table id="shopping-basket">
<colgroup span="5" class="columns">
</colgroup>
<!-- Shopping Basket contents -->
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Title</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Colour</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
 <!-- JSON data -->
  <tbody id="content">

 </tbody>
 </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/test.js"></script>
```

The javaScript is in 2 files first the JSON.

```
[
            {
                "title": "Product 1",
                "size": "Small",
                "colour": "Black",
                "quantity": "1",
                "price": "3.99"
            },
            {
                "title": "Product 2",
                "size": "Medium",
                "colour": "Red",
                "quantity": "1",
                "price": "13.99"
            },
            {
                "title": "Product 3",
                "size": "Small",
                "colour": "Blue",
                "quantity": "2",
                "price": "7.99"
            },
            {
                "title": "Product 4",
                "size": "Medium",
                "colour": "Black",
                "quantity": "1",
                "price": "9.00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Product 5",
                "size": "Large",
                "colour": "Orange",
                "quantity": "1",
                "price": "4.50"
            }

        ]
```

Finally the JavaScript file to with the events.

```
$(function() { /*--- get JSON ----------------------*/
  $.getJSON('javascript/testobject.json', function(data) {
    var table = '<table>';
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      table += '<tr class="editable"><td>' + item.title + '</td><td>' + item.size + '</td><td>' + item.colour + '</td><td><input type="button" class="minus" value="-" /><input type="text" class="figure" value="' + item.quantity + ' "/><input type="button" class="plus" value="+" /></td><td>' + item.price + '</td></tr>';
    });
    table += '</table>';
    $("#content").html(table);
  }); /*------ plus fn ----------------------*/
  $(document).on('click', "input[type='button'].minus", function() {
    var selected_row = ($(this).parent().parent());
    selected_row.addClass('selected');
    var d_value = $(".figure").val();
    d_value--;
    if (d_value === 0) {
      selected_row.hide();
      return null;
    }
    $(".figure").val(d_value);
  }); /*------ minus fn ----------------------*/
  $(document).on('click', "input[type='button'].plus", function() {
    var i_value = $(".figure").val();
    i_value++;
    if (i_value === 11) { /*----alert("INC HELLO");----*/
      return null;
    }
    $(".figure").val(i_value);
  });
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
                PLEASE NOTE I AM HAVING A PROBLEM WITH THE COLLECTION '.FIGURE' CLASS
                INSTEAD OF IMCREMENTING 1 AT A TIME IT IS INCREMENTING & DECREMENTING
                ALL THE VALUES AT THE SAME TIME.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
});
```

Comment: Hi SHanley. Thank you for your help, using keyword 'this' to get to the sibling selector

Answer (score 0):

Since your selector which you're using to set the value is `$('.figure')`, you're selecting all elements with that class instead of just the one in the row. There's a number of ways you could deal with the issue - you could either switch to giving each one a unique ID and use those to select, or an easy way to work around this would be to narrow where you're looking for your selected item -- I'd suggest `$(this).siblings('.figure')` so that you only select from the siblings of the clicked button, rather than from all elements in the DOM.